# Rotation issue with CoordinatorLayout and DrawerLayout

Tags: android

I have set up a DrawerLayout and a CoordinatorLayout in order to use a modern layout with a NavigationView and collapsing toolbar.

It works just fine until the device is rotated. Then the `main_content` is moved to a new permanent location. If I remove the `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` from the main_content FrameLayout rotation works, but the content is no longer aware of the Toolbar.

Any advice?

---

[image]

[image]

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00ff00">
        <!-- ACTIONBAR START -->
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:background="#ff0000">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <!-- ACTIONBAR END -->

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT START -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:background="#0000ff"/>
        <!-- MAIN CONTENT END -->
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView ...>
    <!-- NavigationView code omitted ... -->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml** (loaded into `main_content`)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".fragments.MainFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `main_content` is moved to a new permanent location after rotation?And do you have separate layout files for `landscape`, `w700dp` etc. etc.

Comment: You can see in the landscape screenshot that `main_content` (the blue view) is moved to the bottom. It stays at the same top offset when I rotate back to portrait. I only have this one layout file for the activity – and only one for the fragment.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure whether you had a separate `layout` for landscape orientations where you were removing/altering `main_content`. I assume you are loading a `Fragment` into your `FrameLayout` as well - could you post the `xml` for that too please? **Edit:** Also, I've noticed your `AppBarLayout` height is set to `wrap_content`. Is there any reason for that? There probably wont be any scrolling behaviour if it's the same height as the `Toolbar`

Comment: I've edited to post to add the fragment layout. I have no thought out reason  for setting `wrap_content` on the AppBarLayout. It seemed to work (I'm rather new to Android from an iOS background) and I assumed that AppBarLayout had nothing to do with anything outside of the Toolbar.

Comment: Ok - I've put together an answer that's a few things I've spotted which should hopefully resolve your issue!

Comment: try this https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points that should collectively resolve your problem:

- The height of the `AppBarLayout` determins the expanded size of the collapsing toolbar, whilst the `Toolbar` determins the collapsed size. As such, you should set the `AppBarLayout` height to something more than the `Toolbar` (i.e. `280dp`) to see the collapsing behaviour.
- Immediately inside the `AppBarLayout` should be a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, which contains the `Toolbar` and, optionally, other views too (normally an `ImageView` with a `parallax` collapse mode)
- For the toolbar to collapse and expand correctly, it relies on a `ViewGroup` that supports nested scrolling (`RecyclerView` or `NestedScrollView`. As such, in your example you should try either changing `main_content` from a `FrameLayout` to a `NestedScrollView`, or conversely change the `FrameLayout` that forms the root layout of `Fragment` into a `NestedScrollView`.

Here is an example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            app:contentScrim="@color/primary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/header_image"
                android:src="@drawable/header_image"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:contentDescription="@string/header_image"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I appreciate the help! When I tried this what happened is 1. the toolbar lost it's title and 2. the view entered the undesirable state immediately (the state that used to occur on rotation). The toolbar lost it's background color, but that was easily fixed by adding an `android:background` property to the toolbar item.

Comment: @Christoffer The `Toolbar` should automatically take the `primary` colour of your app if you are using `AppCompat`. Does the `AppTheme` in your `styles.xml` file have a `Theme.AppCompat.x` parent and a `colorPrimary` attribute? Also, you may need to use `setSupportActionBar(yourToolbar)` in your `Activity`, and ensure your `Activity` extends `AppCompatActivity`. Finally...is the toolbar collapsing now when you interact with the screen?

Comment: It sort of started working when I upgraded from API and support libraries from 22 to 23. `getSupportActionBar.setTitle()` still does nothing visible though.

Comment: @Christoffer You may need to set it on your `CollapsingToolbarLayout` instead. You could try `setTitle()` and/or `setTitleEnabled()` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)